# Can I use Zend Dom Query to query other html attributes such as ALT

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-dom-query

Using Zend Dom Query I would like to search **HTML** to find **certain attributes.**

Take the following image as an example.

```
<img id="active-main-image"  src="/images/example.jpg" alt="Image 1234" class="product-image">
```

Instead of using `$this->_xhtml->query('img#active-main-image');` I would like to find the image by using the **alt** attribute.

Pseudo ->  `$this->_xhtml->query('img alt Image 1234');`

I can see why this method is not conventionally popular however, when equipped with nothing but the **Alt value** of a certain image on a page, I see no alternative.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zend_Dom_Query](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.dom.query.html) has a `queryXpath` method that will accept valid xpath queries.

Untested but this should work :

```
$dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($html);
$img = $dom->queryXpath("//img[@alt='Image 1234']");
```